# Follow and Share Button is missing from SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, feature, button, homepage, missing

[image]

follow and share Button is missing from SharePoint online site. have activated the following content even though the options are not displaying.  is there any option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the steps below.

1. Using an admin user to check if the two buttons exists.
2. Using IE/Chrome F12 check if those buttons hide using CSS.
3. Check if the button have removed at Master page level.

Reference: [How to Hide Share, Follow and Sync Buttons in Sharepoint 2013](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/02/how-to-disable-share-follow-sync-buttons-in-sharepoint-2013.html)